# Custom mapping of a JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON from which I want to map the keys and generate another JSON. In the order_data I want to print all child table data and then in last I want to put parent table data

Following is my function from which I am generating JSON

```
public function example(){
        $data = '{"details":[{"price":"4","selectedSubOptionsIds":[],"dis":"27025"},{"price":"1","selectedSubOptionsIds":[63138, 63137],"dis":"27027"}],"a":"1238","b":"2","c":"0","d":"NULL"}';
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $pz['a'] = $data->a; 
        $pz['b'] = $data->b; 
        $pz['c'] = $data->c; 
        $pz['d'] = $data->d; 
        $detailing = $data->details; //this is an array
        $j=0;

        foreach ($detailing as  $value) {

            $subOptIds = $value->selectedSubOptionsIds;  //this is an array  
            $dis = $this->db->from('parent')->where('id',$value->dis)->get()->row();
            $i=0;
            if(count($subOptIds) <= 0){
                $detail[$i]['a'] = $dis->name;
                $detail[$i]['b'] = $dis->id;
                $detail[$i]['c'] = $dis->price;
                $i++;
            } 

            else{ 
                foreach ($subOptIds as $suboptid) {
                    $subopt = $this->db->from('child')->where('id',$suboptid)->get()->row();
                    $detail[$i]['a'] = $subopt->name;
                    $detail[$i]['b'] = $subopt->id;
                    $detail[$i]['c'] = $subopt->price; 
                    $i++;
                }
            }


            $j++;
        }
        $pz['order_data'] = $detail;
        echo json_encode($pz);
     }
```

it return me the json:

```
{
  "a": "1238",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "0",
  "d": "NULL",
  "order_data": Array[2][
    {
      "0": {
        "a": "Test Dish 1",
        "b": "27025",
        "c": "100.0"
      },
      "a": "Pepsi",
      "b": "63138",
      "c": "40.0"
    },
    {
      "a": "Cream",
      "b": "63137",
      "c": "25.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I want order_data array to be a single array and it should only contain objects and should not contain any nested array , Just like below

```
{
  "a": "1238",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "0",
  "d": "NULL",
  "order_data": Array[2][ 
    {
        "a": "Test Dish 1",
        "b": "27025",
        "c": "100.0"
    },
    {

      "a": "Pepsi",
      "b": "63138",
      "c": "40.0"
    },
    {
      "a": "Cream",
      "b": "63137",
      "c": "25.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as far as I can see it's impossible for the code you've shown to produce the output you claim in the question - see demo at https://eval.in/1032176

Secondly, disregarding the above, to get the output you actually want, you simply need to address one small mistake. Move `$i=0;` outside your outer `foreach` loop - presently it gets reset each time you loop through each item in `$detailing`, and therefore the first entry (index `0`) in the `$details` array gets overwritten on subsequent loops. You also don't need `$j=0;` at all, it isn't used anywhere.

Snippet:

```
//...
$detailing = $data->details; //this is an array
$i=0; //changed this

foreach ($detailing as  $value) {
//...
```

See working demo at https://eval.in/1032185

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used array_push() and it also worked for me.